# How can I make the borderRadius of the DropdownButton differ from the borderRadius of its dropdown menu?

Tags: flutter, dropdown

dropdown menu

[image]

DropdownButton

[image]

```dart
 DropdownButton(
    isExpanded: true,
    menuMaxHeight: 100,
    //isDense: true,
    dropdownColor: Colors.amber,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
    items: ['widget.list', 'l', 'l']
        .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
              value: value,
              child: Text(
                value,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ))
        .toList(),
    icon: const Icon(
      Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
    iconSize: 32,
    elevation: 4,
    underline: Container(height: 0),
    style: const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    ),
    onChanged: (newValue) {
      setState(() {
        //selectedRemind = newValue!;
      });
    },
  );
```

Comment: can you include an image what are you expecting

Comment: I didn't understand you

Answer (score 0):

****Try below code****

```
 Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blueAccent,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50)),
          ),
          child: DropdownButton(
            isExpanded: true,
            menuMaxHeight: 100,
            //isDense: true,
            dropdownColor: Colors.amber,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            items: ['widget.list', 'l', 'l']
                .map((value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(
                        value,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ))
                .toList(),
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            iconSize: 32,
            elevation: 4,
            underline: Container(height: 0),
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              setState(() {
                //selectedRemind = newValue!;
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: Does not work the same problem appears